# How to make MPMoviePlayerController respect the ring/silent switch?

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, silent

I'm trying, unsuccessfully, to get the MPMoviePlayerController to play movies silently if the ring/silent switch on the iPhone is set to silent.  There are no interface methods to help me out nor does the player respect the AudioSessionProperty() trick:

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound;

AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

AudioSessionSetProperty(
    kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
    sizeof (sessionCategory),
    &sessionCategory);
```

Has anyone had any success silencing movie playback?

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time trying to get this to work myself.  Eventually I gave up after trying, failing and reading  [this post on the apple dev forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/142085).

> "The MPMoviePlayerController establishes its own audio session and there is nothing you can do to affect this"

Answer (score 0):

`MPMoviePlayerController` has a property `useApplicationAudioSession` that will allow the player to respect the device's silence setting.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
player.useApplicationAudioSession = YES;
[player play];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your code:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
```